# Google sites are not accessible under VPN when using a particular ISP

Tags: vpn, troubleshooting, isp, google-search

after connecting to a VPN using a particular ISP, I cannot access [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).

`ping www.google.com` is not working. This is the output:

```
$ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (216.58.200.196): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
```

But other sites like [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com) are working perfectly.

If I change the ISP or disconnect the VPN, everything is working fine.

I have been also trying to use `traceroute` to find out the which IPs the request is going through in the different conditions, but have not been able to get much success. It seems, for `traceroute www.google.com` , with the particular VPN and ISP, the request is circling back to same IP three times, and then a timeout occurs.

How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Can you add the output of the other diagnostic steps you've performed also? (e.g. the traceroute).  Also, it is useful to include the output of the same commands when you are NOT using the ISP + VPN combination that is problematic.  Finally, can you share information on the DNS configuration (also for both a functional connection and a dysfunctional connection) as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound like you've done a lot to troubleshoot so far, so great job!

In particular, you now have made the problem reproducible, and further, have narrowed down the circumstances of the problem to:

- ISP A (name picked at random), AND
- VPN B (name picked at random), AND
- Connecting to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).

It sounds like if you change any one of these, the problem does not occur, so it is some combination of these things.  This means that you can start to collect data on this situation, and you can compare to any number of others (ISP C, not being connected to VPN B, or connecting to a site other than [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) and look for differences.  https://www.youtube.com is a particularly good one, since YouTube is owned by Google.

To actual diagnosis.

You mention: "not working", but don't give details (what is the error message, what happens?).  Those would be helpful in figuring out what is happening.

What happens when you try to connect to (e.g.) [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) while you are connected to the VPN is:

- Your computer tries to resolve the hostname [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) (What resolvers does it use? Do these differ if you are not connected to VPN B using ISP A? Do these resolution attempts pass encrypted through ISP A and then to VPN B to resend, or are you using ISP A's resolvers unencrypted?)
- Your computer then attempts a connection, presumably using encrypted packets that pass through ISP A. (Are these packets encrypted?  Are they different in any discernable way from encrypted packets that are eventually destined for [www.youtube.com?](http://www.youtube.com?))
- These packets arrive at VPN B's systems, where they are decrypted and re-sent unencrypted (at least the VPN layer is unencrypted). (Is the VPN provider treating these messages differently? (it probably can tell that you are reaching out to Google)  Is Google treating requests from the VPN provider differently for some reason?)
- Then [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) must reply to these packets. (Is there something about this reply that means it cannot successfully traverse the reverse path when it is through VPN B and then ISP A?)

Of these, possible problem locations, some of these options are maybe less likely.

Comment: I have added the output of `ping www.google.com` and other details to my question.